How can I connect an up-to-date django server to a MySQL 5.1 database? (upgrading the MySQL version is not an option)
I have a MySQL-server that is part of a software system that is not developed by me. Thus it is not possible for me to upgrade that MySQL-server to a newer version, because it might break the software system's ability to interact with that database.
I need read access to that database on my public facing django application. The django version is the latest LTS (4.2).
Django's documentation lists two database API driver options for MySQL:

mysqlclient
MySQL Connector/Python

Both of these in their most current versions do not support access to MySQL 5.1 servers
Option 1. still works on Debian 11, with some overwritten methods in a subclass, but not on Debian 12.
How do I ensure that my django application still works, when I upgrade its production server from Debian 11 to 12?
I have tried using MySQL Connector/Python with the option use_pure, but it gives me the error django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1193, "1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'default_storage_engine'", 'HY000').
I am unsure what I would have to patch, when subclassing that, in order to restore compatibility with MySQL 5.1.

You should just freeze the outdated versions of Python, Connector/Python, and Debian, if you can't upgrade MySQL.

At some point down the line it will likely be necessary to upgrade our other components, so we would prefer to find a solution that does not contradict that.

How do you plan to upgrade the other components? They might cause the software to break too.

Well, exactly that concern is why we are looking at problems like this ahead of time.

I found a solution for my specific use-case. It boils down to subclassing django's mysql database backend (django.db.backends.mysql) and adapting the parameters it passes to mysqlclient (MySQLdb.connect) when connecting to the legacy MySQL-server.
